# Что означает & в Python?

Tags: python

Всем добрый вечер! Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает оператор & в Python? (это не связано с множеством).
Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

Comment: «Это называется лоренцева инвариантность и ковариантность. Поищите в интернете статьи на эту тему — они помогут намного больше, нежели можем мы здесь, в комментариях»

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для чисел & обозначет побитовое "И" ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%98)).
В двоичной системе счисления 2 ** n представляет собой 1, после которой идёт n нулей, а (2 ** n - 1) -- n единиц.
Например, `(dec) 32 = (bin) 100000`, а `(dec) 31 = (bin) 11111`. Среди всех положительных чисел только степени двойки не имеют общих единиц с предыдущим числом.
В коде содержится ошибка: `0` он считает степенью двойки.

Comment: @CrazyElf да нет, (-32) & (-33) = -64

Comment: Да, что-то я не то посмотрел, всё ок